# How to install a bootable Windows 10 Home to a flash drive?

Tags: windows-10, bootable-media

I want to build a Windows 10 Home iso file onto a 16 GB flash drive that has to be able to be bootable.

I want to be able to boot the laptop, press esc, I want the drive to be an available option and be able to launch Windows 10 Home from this point.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at WindowsToGo. If I recall well `Rufus` is able to make a bootable windows usb with persistent data as well.

Answer (score 1):

WinToUSB is a free, lightweight software created to install and run a Windows OS on a USB stick or on a USB hard drive.

Below are links to the website where you can download the software and to an article explaining how to use it.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/WinToUSB.shtml

http://www.pcmag.com/article/352209/how-to-run-windows-10-from-a-usb-drive

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible- at least it won't be smooth.  You would run into issues on each different machine you used it on due to licensing and drivers.

There are programs for this but windows 10 home is not designed for this.

Windows Professional/Enterprise, WindowsPE, MiniXp or a bootable Linux flash drive all jump to my mind.

Here is an article on how to do this with Windows Professional:

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-a-portable-version-of-windows-from-a-usb-dri-1565509124

Comment: Yea that's where the issue is coming from. The license we have is for Windows 10 Home. It works this way for Windows 10 Pro but you can't activate it.

Comment: Environments like, MiniXP and WinPE, cannot be used as a daily operating system.